# send message to telegram channel by bot

Tags: php, sendmessage, telegram-bot

i make a telegram bot with telegram botfather and i make my bot as admin in my public telegram channel , now i want to send message in channel by bot, this is my code for this work :

send.php code is :

```
<?php
    require('telegram-bot-api.php');

    $token = '10**************************************jM';
    $bot = new telegram_bot($token);
    $to = '@myChannel';
    $rs = $bot->send_message($to , 'test' , null, null);
        print_r($rs);
?>
```

and telegram-bot-api.php code is :

```
<?php
class ReplyKeyboardMarkup{
    public $keyboard;
    public $resize_keyboard;
    public $one_time_keyboard;
    public $selective;

    function __construct($resize_keyboard=FALSE, $one_time_keyboard = FALSE, $selective=FALSE){
        $this->keyboard=array();
        $this->keyboard[0]=array();
        $this->resize_keyboard=$resize_keyboard;
        $this->one_time_keyboard=$one_time_keyboard;
        $this->selective=$selective;
    }
    public function add_option($option){
        $this->keyboard = $option;
    }
}
class ReplyKeyboardHide{
    public $hide_keyboard;
    public $selective;

    function __construct($hide_keyboard=TRUE, $selective = FALSE){
        $this->hide_keyboard=$hide_keyboard;
        $this->selective=$selective;
    }
}
class ForceReply{
    public $force_reply;
    public $selective;

    function __construct($force_reply=TRUE, $selective = FALSE){
        $this->force_reply=$force_reply;
        $this->selective=$selective;
    }
}

class telegram_bot{
    private $token;

    private function open_url($url, $method="GET", $data=null){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if($method==="POST"){
            if(isset($data)){
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

            }
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }

    private function control_api($action, $data=NULL){
        $token = $this->token;
        $response = json_decode($this->open_url("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token$action", "POST", $data));
        return $response;
    }

    function __construct($token){
        $this->token=$token;
    }

    public function status(){
        $response = $this->control_api("/getme");
        return($response);
    }

    public function get_updates(){
        $response = $this->control_api("/getUpdates");
        return($response);
    }

    public function send_action($to, $action){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        $data["action"]=$action;
        $response = $this->control_api("/sendChatAction", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_message($to, $msg, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        $data["text"]=$msg;
        $data["disable_web_page_preview"]="true";
        if(isset($id_msg))
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;
        $response = $this->control_api("/sendMessage", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_location($to, $lat, $lon, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        $data["latitude"]=$lat;
        $data["longitude"]=$lon;
        if(isset($id_msg))
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;
        $response = $this->control_api("/sendLocation", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_sticker($to, $sticker, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        if(file_exists($sticker))$sticker="@".$sticker;
        $data["sticker"]=$sticker;
        if(isset($id_msg))
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;
        $response = $this->control_api("/sendSticker", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_video($to, $video, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        if(file_exists($video))$video="@".$video;
        $data["video"]=$video;
        if(isset($id_msg))
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;
        $response = $this->control_api("/sendVideo", $data);
        return $response;
    }

    public function send_photo($to, $photo, $caption, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;

        if(file_exists($photo))$photo="@".$photo;
        $data["photo"]=$photo;
        if(isset($caption)){
            $data["caption"]=$caption;
        }
        if(isset($id_msg)){
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        }
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;

        $response = $this->control_api("/sendPhoto", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_audio($to, $audio, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;

        if(file_exists($audio))$audio="@".$audio;
        $data["audio"]=$audio;
        if(isset($id_msg)){
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        }
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;

        $response = $this->control_api("/sendAudio", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function send_document($to, $document, $id_msg=null, $reply=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;

        if(file_exists($audio))$document="@".$audio;
        $data["document"]=$document;
        if(isset($id_msg)){
            $data["reply_to_message_id"]=$id_msg;
        }
        if(isset($reply))
            $data["reply_markup"]=$reply;

        $response = $this->control_api("/sendDocument", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function forward_message($to, $from, $msg_id){
        $data = array();
        $data["chat_id"]=$to;
        $data["from_chat_id"]=$from;
        $data["message_id"]=$msg_id;
        $response = $this->control_api("/forwardMessage", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function set_webhook($url=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["url"]=$url;
        $response = $this->control_api("/setWebhook", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function get_user_profile_photos($id_user, $offset=null, $limit=null){
        $data = array();
        $data["user_id"]=$id_user;
        if(isset($offset)){
            $data["offset"]=$offset;
        }
        if(isset($limit)){
            $data["limit"]=$limit;
        }

        $response = $this->control_api("/getUserProfilePhotos", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public function read_post_message(){
        return json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }

}
?>
```

but when run send.php not send message to channel but when i replace chat_id with private chat_id or group chat_id , this code done very cool and send a message to group or my contact

Excuse me for my English language , sory :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved , i tested with httpRequster plugin for send a post request to this link :

https://api.telegram.org/bot1*******************************M/sendMessage

and posted parameters is :
chat_id = @myChannel_username
text = myMessage

i don't know why not worked my old code but work this request :D

any way thanks.

Comment: Make sure if this is channel use chat_id=@xxxyxxyxyxyx ,if this is for group you have to use chat_id = -xxyxxxyyxyx  (- in front) . I too had the same problem and resolved . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018486/how-to-send-python-output-to-telegram-channel-not-to-group-and-gmail-email-group

Answer (score 0):

Bot has to be an admin of the channel for it to be able to send messages. None of the clients can help you make a bot an admin of a channel. Are you sure your bot is an admin of the channel?

Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#october-8-2015

Comment: this right but bot can send message to channel if is a admin or can send message to all those who start conversation chat with bot.   

Source : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Answer (score 0):

curl has this problem  for SSL.
add this code to Solve problem :

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numeric chat_id of your channel/group/account to make bot sent messages. 
Easy way to get chat_id is to forward any message from your channel to bot called @userinfobot.